# How to show an existing hiding div?

Tags: javascript

```
 <div>

  <div class="questions_body" style="display: none;">
    
  <div class="questions">

 <div/>
```

the second div is hidden and when I click on a button   it appears automatically and I wanna know how to access it

Comment: Is `questions` meant to be a child of `questions_body`? Your markup isn't easy to parse.

Comment: Yes , questions  div is the child of questions